# Find replace with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field in a table that has a bad character in it.. the rest of the string of text is fine. There is just one character that I need to remove while leaving the rest of the string in place. I was little afraid of replacing all of the data and the posts I was reading were talking about replacing everything and not just a portion of the data.

Comment: Any pointers, direction?

Comment: This is very trivial to Google and I'm at a loss why that's not the first thing you did. Just search for "find replace with mySQL".

Comment: Actually it is the first thing I did. I didn't find exactly what I was looking for so I used the community to confirm. Why all the hate?  I was afraid I would replace everything in the field instead of the specific characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourfield=REPLACE(yourfield,'X','');
```

This will remove all `X` from `yourfield`.

Comment: Downvoted because this is so extremely trivial a question, it should not be on SO in the first place.